Remove - "default-fake-certificate.pem: from GKE K8s ingress controller
My current setup include - ingressController with ingress on GKE k8s cluster.
The issue is self signed certificate is getting served instead of correct certificates.
After debugging looks like default certificates is present in ingresscontroller.
/etc/ingress-controller/ssl$ ls
         default-fake-certificate.pem

My current ingress setup
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-resource
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"


spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - secretName: tls
    hosts:
    - some.domain.com
  rules:
  - host: some.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
            service:
                name: serviceA
                port:
                    number: 9900

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: tls
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data:
  tls.crt: correct_crt
  tls.key: correct_tls

How do I disabled self signed certificated ?

Or any idea, why ingress is not picking correct certificates. ??
